# Как удалить символ '\' из строки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сериализую строку в JSON. После сериализации ниоткуда берутся `'\'`.
Как их убрать? Код:

```js
var date = document.getElementById("data");
var formated = document.getElementById("formated");
let serialize = JSON.stringify(date.value);

formated.value = serialize[1] + "\n";

for (var i = 2; i < serialize.length - 2; i++) {
  if (serialize[i] == ",") {
    formated.value += serialize[i] + "\n";
  } else if (i + 2 == serialize.length) {
    formated.value += serialize[i] + "\n";
  } else {
    formated.value += serialize[i];
  }
}

formated.value += "\n}";
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="data">{"name":"klava" , "age":22}</textarea>
<textarea id="formated"></textarea>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная ошибка в том, что **сериализуется строка**.

Так как в строке присутствуют кавычки, они сериализуются соответствующим способом, а именно с добавляением специ символа, для экранирования.

Для решения достаточно либо убрать ненужный в данном случает [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
var date = document.getElementById("data");
var formated = document.getElementById("formated");
let serialize = date.value; // JSON.stringify(date.value);

formated.value = serialize[0] + "\n"; // индексы в строке начинаются с 0

for (var i = 1; i < serialize.length - 2; i++) {
  if (serialize[i] == ",") {
    formated.value += serialize[i] + "\n";
  } else if (i + 2 == serialize.length) {
    formated.value += serialize[i] + "\n";
  } else {
    formated.value += serialize[i];
  }
}

formated.value += "\n}";
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="data">{"name":"klava" , "age":22}</textarea>
<textarea id="formated"></textarea>
```

Либо, перед сериализацией сначала парсить в настоящий объект, с помощью [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
var date = document.getElementById("data");
var formated = document.getElementById("formated");
let serialize = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(date.value));

formated.value = serialize[0] + "\n"; // индексы в строке начинаются с 0

for (var i = 1; i < serialize.length - 2; i++) {
  if (serialize[i] == ",") {
    formated.value += serialize[i] + "\n";
  } else if (i + 2 == serialize.length) {
    formated.value += serialize[i] + "\n";
  } else {
    formated.value += serialize[i];
  }
}

formated.value += "\n}";
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="data">{"name":"klava" , "age":22}</textarea>
<textarea id="formated"></textarea>
```

---

Либо вообще отказаться от ручного форматирования и использовать параметры метода [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), а именно: третий параметр отвечает за количество пробелов в отступе

```js
var date = document.getElementById("data");
var formated = document.getElementById("formated");

formated.value = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(date.value), null, 2);
formated.value += '\n';
formated.value += JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(date.value), null, 4);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="data">{"name":"klava" , "age":22}</textarea>
<textarea id="formated"></textarea>
```